# Geolocation code returning an empty result

Tags: geolocation, mac-address, google-geolocation

I want to get the device longitude and latitude using the mac address not it's not returning any value.

I have activate my Google Geolocation API and have enable billing. pls help.

```
<?php           
        $mac = "E4:D5:3D:E4:05:BF"; 
        //encode the data in JSON   
    $wifiAccessPoints = array("macAddress"=>$mac);
    $wifiAccessPoints = json_encode($wifiAccessPoints);

    $API_key = "AIzaSyApOf.................";

        $url  = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=$API_key";



        $client = curl_init($url);
        //send the request to resource
        curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $wifiAccessPoints);
        curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

        curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-type: application/json", "Content-Length".strlen($wifiAccessPoints)));

        curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_POST,true);


        //get response from request.
        $response = curl_exec($client);

        //decode format response
        //$result = json_decode($response);
        $status = curl_getinfo($client, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        echo $status."<br>";

        echo $response."<br>";

        ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you receiving any error messages? What are the results of `echo`ing `$status` and `$response`?

Comment: the $status is returning 0 the $response is blank and i'm not receiving any error message

Comment: Try using a tool such as Fiddler or WireShark to see what raw HTTP response is being returned by the API, that will give you a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: this is the error I got: `{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "geolocation", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" } ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } `

Answer (score 0):

The error being returned indicates that your request is formatted correctly, but the API could not find a geolocation for it. The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en#errors) has this to say about your result:

> Reason: **notFound**
>   Domain: **geolocation**
>   Status Code: **404**
>   Description: **The request was valid, but no results were returned.**

So it appears that you are performing your request successfully, but Google will not always be able to tell you where a particular WiFi access point is located (t would be impossible to expect them to know them all).

The documentation also states that

> The request body's wifiAccessPoints array must contain **two or more** WiFi access point objects. macAddress is required; all other fields are optional.

It looks like you only have one access point, a lookup by IP may be ore accurate. [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en#errors) has a wealth of information on how you can reformat your input JSON.